Can’t access remote desktop via VPN
I always have to work on stuff outside of working hours. Recently I couldn’t access to my remote desktop at work, the operating system for both is Windows (Windows 10 Enterprise in the work computer & Windows Pro 11 in the daily use laptop).
I made sure all needed settings are right, even contacted the Active Directory team to check up policies applied to my user. Remote computer only works if someone around at the work try to turn PC on, every time they confirm “PC is on, connected to network... There is no issue”.
Feeling hopeless right now because I need to work and it’s weekend for everyone.

You need to talk with your IT support staff to make sure you are using the tools, systems, and methods they support. They are responsible for making sure you have the tools you need to do the work you are paid to do and that these function. If you ARE IT staff designated to support this function, we'll need more information regarding the system configuration, and what changed between this system working and it now not working.

@music2myear they do support what I’m using, what I’m missing was the switch user option ? I don’t use sleep mode so log off was the only way. Even with all that still not able to access :(

Questions about business-owned computers and networks are off topic on this site for several reasons. You will need to continue working with your IT support staff regarding this.
